# Resetting interval after manual click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using a basic click function to animate an element on Squarespace as a slideshow workaround, but I'm struggling to get the interval timer to reset if someone clicks the button element manually.

Here's the code that's currently running, which clicks the "next" button. The first half just checks to make sure the code isn't running inside Squarespace's editor.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  window.setInterval(function(){
    {$("html:not(.sqs-modal-lightbox-open) body:not(.sqs-edit-mode-active, .sqs-edit-mode) .user-items-list-banner-slideshow__arrow-button--right")
    [0].click()}     
  }, 4500);
});
</script>
```

**I'm just trying to add another 4500 interval if someone clicks the button on their own.** Right now, the timer is running regardless of whether or not a user is engaging with the slideshow, so it can cause some jumpiness. Thank you for any help.

Comment: so create a function that makes the interval. Use clearInterval and than recreate the interval

Answer (score 1):

```js
function timer() {
  return setInterval(() => console.log("Time!"), 4000);
}

function reset() {
  clearInterval(test);
  test = timer()
}

var test = timer();
```

```html
<button onclick="reset()">Click to reset the interval!</button>
```

As @epascarello said, you just need to clear the interval and set it again.

Comment: For the sake of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), move the callback to its own function.

Comment: @freedomn-m That's a fair point. It's fixed now.

Comment: Meant for anyone reading the answer :)  It was fine for an example.

Comment: Since I'm restricted with Squarespace's html, I can't create a button for the onclick function. Is there a way to use the original button element (with the class .user-items-list-banner-slideshow__arrow-button--right)?

Comment: @Cs238975 Yes, you just need to add an event listener to the existing button that makes it do the same thing as the button in my example.